# AS3 flash.net.FileReference.browse() function only shows the lower case extensions (on linux)

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am calling flash.net.FileReference.browse() function to open up a dialog box for user to select a specific type of files (let's say wave files). However, in linux the dialog box only shows the lower case extensions (ie '.wav' extensions) and not upper case extensions (ie '.WAV'). When I run the following code, only the files with '.wav' extensions are shown...

```
var fileReferenceList : FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
var filefilter : FileFilter = new FileFilter("Audio files", "*.WAV;*.wav");
fileReferenceList.browse([filefilter]);
```

Any help to get around this is much appreciated.